# Display LWP::UserAgent download progress

Tags: perl, progress-bar, progress, lwp-useragent

I'm downloading a large file directly to a file with Perl using LWP::UserAgent and the `:content_file` option.

This is a simplified example of my code:

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(3600);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $response = $ua->get(
    'http://example.com/largefile.xml',
    :content_file   => 'path/to/file/largefile.xml'
);

if ($response->is_success) {
    print "File downloaded\n";
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Is there any way to display the percentage of the download status? (or something similiar to `wget` output)

```
10% [===>                                  ]  65.120.154  527K/s
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation for the module](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent).

> **$ua->show_progress**
>
> **$ua->show_progress( $boolean )**
>
> Get/set a value indicating whether a progress bar should be displayed on the terminal as requests are processed. The default is FALSE.

Comment: Also, take a look at source code of /bin/lwp-download  of ActivePerl installation.

Comment: @KostiaShiian: lwp-download isn't specific to ActivePerl. It's [available from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-download).

Answer (score 3):

[Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40511723/257635) has already answered your question but I would like to suggest below 2 modules.

- [LWP::UserAgent::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent::ProgressBar): A subclass of [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) that provides additional methods `get_with_progress` and `post_with_progress`.
- [LWP::UserAgent::ProgressAny](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent::ProgressAny): Uses [Progress::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Progress::Any) framework, therefore, it can be used to record progress to any output.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at both of them aswell.

Comment: LWP::UserAgent::ProgressBar provides a progress bar very much in line with what the OP had in mind.  It's just not likely to be already installed, if that's an issue (eg, for portability)